# Get dependency from pom.xml to List

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I must add all dependencies from pom.xml to List"Dependency"
How i can do it?
To find needed pom i have a "artifactId" and "groupId"
Write an absolute path for Filereader impossible, because project multi-modules
Examples pom.xml:

```
<groupId>ru.aa</groupId>
  <artifactId>testProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.spullara</groupId>
            <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7</version>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You probably need an XML parser and you can read the pom.xml from the project directory of the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: So, are you inside a Java program? Or a Maven plugin? What is the purpose of the list you want to create?

Comment: In my program User choose needed database, then I should get a list with drivers dependency and compare by name. And upload the necessary dependency. All problem, that i don't have a absolute path to file. Only groupid and artifactid

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand what you are up to. If you have (say) five databases, why do you need an automatic way to discover dependencies of their drivers? Maybe you write a new question in which you specifically describe your use case?

Comment: the application is very large and about 50 dependencies should be dumped into the list.  The main question is whether there are any libraries that will enable such unloading and how to do it. From: pom To: List